# importing basics in laravel excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I'm trying to understand how could I use laravel/excel to import my excel files

I tried to do like :

```
public function import()
    { 
        $path = public_path();
        Excel::load($path.'/file.xlsx', function($reader) {

            $firstrow = $reader->first()->toArray();
            dd($firstrow);

        });
    }
```

but when I dump anything dont get any dump from laravel,

this is the data from my excel:

```
item    spool   junta
1       test1   j1
2       test2   j2
3       test3   j3
```

is a simple file just to test but nothing happen, i just get a blank page without my dump

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

you can load this .xls file by using below code:

```
$post = new your_modelname;

$post-> Excel::load('your_sheet.xls', function($reader) {

$reader->setDateColumns(array(
    'created_at',           // for timestamp
    'updated_at' ));

})->get();
```

try this hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i import my files and its working perfectly...

```
$file = $request->file('userfile');

Excel::load($file, function($reader)
{
foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row) 
{
dd($row);
// fire your query here to insert data to db...
}
}
```